# How to display rails server infos with colors in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails-3.2.10 with ruby-1.9.3-head, my question is, when I run

```
rails s
```

how can I have some color in my bash terminal? I wanted to try with the ruby-debug option, but the ruby-debug gemfile only only can not be installed with 1.9.x yet.

Is there a solution?

Comment: There's the option `config.colorize_logging` to put in the environment file to add special chars for colors in log files, but I'm not sure it works for the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried [this](http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/beautiful-logging-for-ruby-on-rails-3-2/) and it works perfect in Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 2.0.0. You can customize colors and messages.

That solution is also in the form of a [gem](https://github.com/jrochkind/formatted_rails_logger).

```
gem 'formatted_rails_logger'
```

Gem is better formatted but is not colorized. I prefer the first solution.

Regards!

EDIT:

Try gem [meta_request](https://github.com/qqshfox/meta_request) and [Rails Panel](https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel) chrome extension. You can see the server log in your browser well organized, showing params, SQL queries, etc.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It is a start for wrapping in color the output.

I search more something like display errors in red, the type of the request, the url, etc all in different colors, The stack trace and the application also in different color. I don't really know, I search for some cool stuff. Currently I begin to be used on the rails errors. I still need to browse into the text to find what I want (the error, some puts debug stuff, etc) where rails could factorise more some stuff.

Comment: Give it a try to gem meta_request and Rails Panel chrome extension. You can see the server log in your browser well organized, showing params, SQL queries, etc.

Comment: This gem+Chrome extension is really good!! Thank you very much. It shows exactly what I wanted, the SQL queries, the params, the view, etc... Thank you very much! PS: please update you answer to make it match with your new update!