# Syntax highlighting in Rails Server log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to get the rails server to output errors etc in colour? This would be a real help! It's very frustrating to just see a 'sea' of errors and have to scan through them every time.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks promising - http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/beautiful-logging-for-your-ruby-on-rails-application/

Comment: Check this out. Hopefully helps. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161869/how-to-display-rails-server-infos-with-colors-in-terminal